# Wi-Fi is connected but the device shows "Wi-Fi has no internet access"

Tags: wi-fi, connection-issues

I recently reconfigured my modem and now only my Nexus phone have problem in connecting to Wi-Fi but other devices work correctly. It  connects to Wi-Fi and works but a message appears in notification:

> Wi-Fi has no internet access

The next time when I turn on Wi-Fi  my phone  doesn't connect automatically to a Wi-Fi.

How can I fix this problem?

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]

Comment: are your other devices able to access internet with the same wifi?

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting other devices to the network - if they can connect to the internet, it might be a (strange) issue with your phone, possibly caused by the reconfiguration somehow - "forget" the network, and then reconnect to it. Otherwise, your router may not have or may not be providing internet access to devices on WiFi, also possibly caused by the reconfiguration somehow (however this one seems more likely).